# bad window path name python

Tags: python, tkinter

my code was working fine before i added a block of code `def startcheck(self):`and i'm not sure what's wrong with it. please tell me what im doing wrong, thanks. here's what it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MathsQuiz/venv/test 2.py", line 138, in <module>
    instance = Starting(root)
  File "C:/MathsQuiz/venv/test 2.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.usercont = Button(self.frame, text="Continue", command=self.startcheck())
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame"
```

here's a small part of my code:

```
class Starting:
    def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
                self.usern = Label(self.frame,text="Please enter a username:", font=("16"))
        self.usern.grid(row=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.userentry = Entry(self.frame, width=50)
        self.userentry.grid(row=2)
        self.name = StringVar()
        self.name.set(self.userentry.get())
        self.usercont = Button(self.frame, text="Continue", command=self.startcheck())
        self.usercont.grid(row=3)
    
    def startcheck(self):
        if self.name.get() == None:
            nameerror = Label(self.frame, text="Please enter a username")
            nameerror.grid(row=5)
        else:
            self.clear1()

    def clear1(self):
        self.frame.destroy()
        Question1(root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   root.title = ("Maths Quiz")
   instance = Starting(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things will get you up and running:

- `add self.frame = master` as the first line to your `__init__` method
- change `command=self.startcheck()` to `command=self.startcheck`, the command argument expects a callable (whereas with the parentheses it's already been called)
- The snippet doesn't have a `Question1` class but I imagine that is somewhere else in your code
- should use `self.name.get() == ""` instead of `== None` which should never be true as `StringVar.get()` returns a string. The other more concise way to do this is to use: `if self.name.get(): {true condition} else {false condition}`. This takes advantage of python's truthiness where the empty string evaluates to False

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed multiple things you need to correct. First and most important is that you are referring multiple times to `self.frame` which does not exists as your class is not inherited from `tk.Frame`. Below I fixed your code using `master` instead of self.frame:

```
from tkinter import *

class Starting:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.usern = Label(master ,text="Please enter a username:", font=("16"))
        self.usern.grid(row=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.userentry = Entry(master, width=50)
        self.userentry.grid(row=2)
        self.name = StringVar()
        self.name.set(self.userentry.get())
        self.usercont = Button(master, text="Continue", command=lambda: self.startcheck(master))
        self.usercont.grid(row=3)
    
    def startcheck(self, master):
        if self.name.get() == None:
            nameerror = Label(master, text="Please enter a username")
            nameerror.grid(row=5)
        else:
            self.clear1(master)

    def clear1(self, master):
        master.destroy()
        Question1(root)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title = ("Maths Quiz")
    instance = Starting(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Also command = self.startcheck() will not work because of the parentheses (it calls the function, rather than specify it as a call-back function).
Above I passed master to functions, but instead you can also include `self.master = master` in `__init__()` and then refer to `self.master` instead. In that case, you don't have to pass master as parameter.

```
# Obviously it throws an error when arriving at Question1
```

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple issues:

- First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).
- Read [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)
- Read [why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228)
- PyLint Report, fix accordingly:

```
question.py:1:0: W0401: Wildcard import tkinter (wildcard-import)
question.py:5:27: E1101: Instance of 'Starting' has no 'frame' member (no-member)
question.py:8:31: E1101: Instance of 'Starting' has no 'frame' member (no-member)
question.py:12:31: E1101: Instance of 'Starting' has no 'frame' member (no-member)
question.py:4:23: W0613: Unused argument 'master' (unused-argument)
question.py:16:11: C0121: Comparison to None should be 'expr is None' (singleton-comparison)
question.py:17:30: E1101: Instance of 'Starting' has no 'frame' member (no-member)
question.py:24:8: E1101: Instance of 'Starting' has no 'frame' member (no-member)
question.py:25:8: E0602: Undefined variable 'Question1' (undefined-variable)
```

Comment: This reads more like a rant against the quality of the code rather than an attempt to answer the question.